# Canvas.SetLeft not working with animations

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, canvas

I am doing 'fancy' animations on `Label` control in WPF, using `Storyboard` and `DoubleAnimations`.

```
private void SetAnimation()
{
        _storyboard = new Storyboard();

        var slideDuration =
            new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(((label.ActualWidth - ActualWidth + (double.IsNaN(Canvas.GetLeft(label)) ? 0 : Canvas.GetLeft(label)))*1.0)/_pixelsPerSecond*1000));

        var slideAnim = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            From = double.IsNaN(Canvas.GetLeft(label)) ? 0 : Canvas.GetLeft(label),
            To = (label.ActualWidth - ActualWidth) * -1,
            Duration = slideDuration,
            BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
        };

        Storyboard.SetTarget(slideAnim, label);            
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slideAnim, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Left)"));            

        _storyboard.Children.Add(slideAnim);
        _storyboard.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;

}
```

However, after the `Storyboard` is played, with `Storyboard.Begin()`, `Canvas.SetLeft` stops working. It just doesn't change anything at all, even if I stop the `Storyboard` through `Storyboard.Stop()`.

Any ideas?

Comment: try setting `_storyboard.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;`. `Storyboard` has almost [highest priority](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms743230(v=vs.100).aspx#listing) and until it holds end value you won't be able to change it

Comment: Strangely, this has not helped, but your link surely did. I posted the answer which has worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I managed it to work eventually. Alhough dkozl solution in comment under question has not worked, his link guided me to answer, which I found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970493(v=vs.100).aspx).

The line that allowed me to make changes again was

```
label.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, null);
```

which effectively stops animating this property.